# Angular How to inject HttpClient in an Angular Service

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript

I want a **service** which uses http requests.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class BackendService {
  private backendUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //not done as observable
  uploadImage(image: any) {
    let formData = new FormData()
    formData.append("image",image);

    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.backendUrl}/upload`, formData);
  }
}
```

and a **component** in which i want to inject it:

```
import { BackendService } from '../backend-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-picker',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatCardModule,CommonModule,MatButtonModule,MatIconModule],
  templateUrl: './image-picker.component.html',
  styleUrl: './image-picker.component.css'
})
export class ImagePickerComponent {
  selectedImage: string | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined = null;

  constructor(private backendService: BackendService){}
}
```

This however throws me a`NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!` Error.

In the tutorial they appear to add the services to the `app.module.ts`. However I dont have an `app.module.ts` and the current way to is to use standalone components.

How can i resolve this? Do i *need* to create the `app.module.ts` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `provideHttpClient()` from `@angular/common/http` to the `providers` of `AppConfig` (or directly to `bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {providers: [...]})`)

Comment: What is 'provideHttpClient()'? Where does it come from? Also where does AppModule come from? I dont have a file named that way.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot!

Although Angular should probably update their tutorial, as app.module.ts is not the default anymore in Angular 17

Comment: This has been done on the new docs site : https://angular.dev !

Answer (score 2):

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
};
```

should fix your problem